# Can a halting turing machine write any combination on a tape before halting?

Tags: computational-complexity, turing-machines

Assume, a halting turing machine uses $n$ items of the tape. Can it write every
 possible combination on this $n$ items before halting ?

We start with a blank tape.

Example $n=2$ , alphabet $0,1$

The machine could make the task as follows : It prints a $1$ (combination $10$)
 goes to the right, prints a $1$ again (combination $11$) , goes to the left,
 prints a $0$ (combination $01$) and halts. So, it used only $2$ items and all
 possible combinations occured ($00$ occured at the start)

Comment: You mean like, for $n = 2$: Is there a Turing machine writing down "00", "01", "10", and "11" on the tape and then stopping? I don’t get what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, your example is exactly what I mean.

Comment: But in this case, the turing machine is only allowed to use $2$ items on the tape.

Comment: The combinations should not occur at the end, every combination should appear at some time (at some step of the turing machine). So, in our example, the combinations $00,01,10,11$ must occur in any order and the machine must halt then. To make things not too complicated, we start with a blank tape.

Comment: Do you want every combination to be printed *exactly once* during computation?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Maybe you can improve my question, I think my formulation is somewhat unlucky.

Comment: @JessicaB The question is whether such a sequence can be computed (and how).

Comment: A more interesting question would be whether there's a Turing machine that works for all tape lengths: If it is started at the left end of a tape reading $0^{n-1}1$, then it will eventually terminate after having had the tape in each of the $2^n$ possible states at least once, and without ever trying to move beyond that initial word.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. A Turing Machine can carry out *any* finite set of instructions, and what you desire is certainly finite. You just have it start in state $1$, do whatever you want, then go to state $2$, do something, go to state $3$, etc.. You'll have a lot of states in your machine, but it's still a Turing machine. You could be a bit more sophisticated and implement a Turing machine specified as follows. It starts in state $0$ and proceeds as:

- State 0: If you read a $0$, write a $1$ and don't move the head. Stay in state $0$. Otherwise, transition to state $+1$ and move the head right.
- State +1: If you read a $0$, write a $1$ and move the head left. Transition to state $-1$. Otherwise, transition to state $+2$ and move the head right.
- State $+i$: If you read a $0$, write a $1$ and move the head left. Transition to state $-i$. Otherwise, transition to state $n+1$ and move the head right.

...

- State $+n-1$: If you read a $0$, write a $1$ and move the head left. Transition to state $-(n-1)$. Halt otherwise.

...

- State $-1$: Write a $0$ and transition to state $0$.
- State $-i$: Write a $0$, move the head left, and transition to state $-(i-1)$.

This is probably the simplest machine that can count in binary without using additional positions on the tape (e.g. if we mark where the start and end of the string is with a different character, then it only takes two states, excluding the halting state). It basically counts how many $1$s it has seen when it is incrementing, finds the first $0$, changes it to a $1$, then backtracks, zeroing the previous digits.

Comment: Does this also work for more than $2$ symbols and did you consider that the machine can only use the given $n$ items ? It wouls be interesting to find the turing machine with the least possible number of states that does the job.

Comment: You could modify it for symbols $0,1,\ldots,k-1$ if you change the instruction of state $+i$ to "If you read some $j<k-1$, write $j+1$. Transition to state $-i$. Otherwise, transition to state $i+1$". And yes, this machine only uses $n$ items - it doesn't so much as look at the others - you can simulate it by hand, if you like. I *suspect* that one state could be eliminated from my algorithm. I would expect that it is a very hard problem to figure out the simplest machine accomplishing the task - though maybe post that as a separate question and see if anyone has an answer.